# What is the name of the number that is being added to another number?

Tags: terminology, arithmetic

What is the name of the number that is being added to another number?

I am writting a paper, and I want to know how to call the number that you add to another number (for example: 2+4, how can I call the four without saying the word "4"). Thanks.

Comment: Addend. ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Either *[addend](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/addend)* or *[summand](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/summand)* is correct.  If you are adding more than two numbers, it might be more appropriate to use the term addend or summand to refer to any term being added, e.g.
$$\text{summand} + \text{summand} + \dotsb + \text{summand} = \text{sum (or total)} $$
or
$$\text{addend} + \text{addend} + \dotsb + \text{addend} = \text{sum (or total)}. $$
If you need to refer to a specific term, the phrase "the $n$-th summand (or addend)" gets the job done.

In a case when you are adding exactly two numbers, you can use *[augend](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/augend)* and *addend*, to refer to the first and second terms in a summation, i.e. you can write
$$\text{augend} + \text{addend} = \text{sum}.$$
That being said, this use of the term "addend" is not unambiguous: for example, [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Addend.html) defines "summand" as a synonym of addend, with [augend](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Augend.html) referring to the first summand (or addend) in any sum.  Hence it might be inadvisable to use "addend" to refer to only the second term in a sum, as the term "addend" is not unambiguously understood in this way; it could refer to any term in a sum.  Moreover, the term "augend" is somewhat esoteric, and its use will likely draw requests for clarification.

Comment: *augend* seems esoteric to me

Comment: @Ooker Personally, I find anything other than "summand" to be kind of esoteric,  I would rather write "the second summand" than "the addend," as there is no chance of ambiguity with the former.  That being said, if each summand is going to be given a distinct word, "augend" and "addend" are the correct terms.

Comment: Hmm... Probably it is different in different countries. I did elementary schooling in India, and "addend" is the word we were taught there. This is the first time that I have seen "summand".

Comment: I don't recall using any of these terms during my education up to and including BSc Maths.  Conversely my 2nd grader already has already needed to use *addend* in her homework.  YMMV.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma In my Google bubble, a search for "summand" returns about 1 million results, while a search for "addend" returns about 2.4 million results (indicating that while "addend" is somewhat more common, "summand" should not be seen as terribly out there).  "augend" returns about a tenth as many results, indicating that it *is* significantly less common (i.e. esoteric).  As for my own experience, while the term "addend" is not unfamiliar to me, "summand" is a term that I have seen much more often in my own life.

Comment: That being said, the first several hits for both "summand" and "addend" give nearly the same definition, hence I would argue that calling $b$ the "addend" of the expression $a+b$ is ambiguous, and it would be better to say that $b$ is the *second* addend (or summand, whatever your preference is).

Answer (score 12):

The word you're looking for is [addend](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/addend#Noun).

Answer (score 5):

The word **summand** would denote $2$ as well as $4$ in your example, and is not what you want.

Then, **augend** would denote the $2$ alone, and **addend** the $4$ alone.

Answer (score 5):

*Addend* is not a very familiar term, whereas *summand* makes no distinction between the number being added *to* and the number being added. Perhaps the term you are looking for is simply *increment*.  This is certainly in common use in calculus when you speak of $\Delta x$ as being the $x$-increment and evaluate $f$ at $x+\Delta x$.